# automated python script via vm

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell, ssh

I'm new in a company for IT and very few people here know Python so I can't ask then for help.

The problem: I need to create a script in Python that connects via ssh from my VM to my client server, after I access with my script I need to find a log file and search for a few data.

I tested my script within my Windows with a copy of that file and it searched everything that I need. However, I don't know how to do that connection via SSH.

I tried like this but I don't know where to start:

```
 from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
 import sys 

 ssh = subprocess.check_output(['ssh', 'my_server', 'password'], shell = True)
 ssh.stdin.write("cd /path/")
 ssh.stdin.write("cat file | grep err|error")
```

This generates a error "name 'subprocess' is not defined".
I don't understand how to use the subprocess nor how to begin to develop the solution.

Note: I can't use Paramiko because I don't have permission to install packages via pip or download the package manually.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: To fit into the company culture, you might want to program in a language more widely used within the company.

Comment: the company told me to use with python and the version on the machine is 3.4

Comment: i dont need the code runing just a how to get there, i already look for official documentation on subprocess,paramiko,python,linux and Popen even try to do most thing via terminal like a crontab to do a few commands for me i keep talking to my teachers in school also but im having a difficult time to solve this part since i rarely used vms

Comment: since my script is going to have to stay on a proxy server and there execute him to acess my client server find a log read and collect the information in monitoring tool called zabbix i feel kinda lost since i only a intern and even my boss dont know how to assist me

Comment: You're going to have one problem after another trying to invoke the ssh program from python. For one thing, it's extremely difficult to use password authentication that way. I know you said you can't use paramiko, but you should push back on that.

Comment: yes after all the research and many opinions the paramiko is the best and i even try to install it so i can use but since neither me or my boss can install they say try to find another way, i have a deadline to 7 september so i have sometime to try whitout the paramiko. i already researching on how to do everything via shell script since half i already know most the commands that i need but since they ask in python i have to try to make work

Answer (score 0):

You didn't import `subprocess` itself so you can't refer to it.

`check_output` simply runs a process and waits for it to finish, so you can't use that to run a process you want to interact with.  But there is nothing interactive here, so let's use that actually.

The first argument to `subprocess.Popen()` and friends is *either* a string for the shell to parse, with `shell=True`; or a list of token passed directly to `exec` with no shell involved. (On some platforms, passing a list of tokens with `shell=True` actually happens to work, but this is coincidental, and could change in a future version of Python.)

`ssh myhost password` will try to run the command `password` on `myhost` so that's not what you want. *Probably* you should simply set things up for passwordless SSH in the first place.

... But you can use this syntax to run the commands in one go; just pass the shell commands to `ssh` as a string.

```
from subprocess import check_output
#import sys                          # Remove unused import

 result = check_output(['ssh', 'my_server',
     # Fix quoting and Useless Use of Cat, and pointless cd
     "grep 'err|error' /path/file"])
```